# Using Notebook as second Monitor for Ubuntu Tablet

Tags: multiple-monitors, vnc, tablet

I am planning my new mobile development working station consisting of a Notebook and a Tablet as second monitor.

Notebook OS: Windows 8.1
Tablet OS: Ubuntu (14 LTS)

I have asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588913/using-ubuntu-tablet-as-second-monitor-for-windows-8-1) how I can achieve to simulate the Ubuntu Tablet as second monitor on Windows.

Now I want to know: how can I achieve using the Windows Notebook display, keyboard and mouse for controlling the Ubuntu OS that runs on the tablet. Like a VNC Session started on Windows (targeting the Ubuntu tablet), but instead of mirroring a display, I want to use it as an extension.

Therefore when I start the program on Windows and connect to the tablet, Ubuntu should see an additional monitor.